# Validation Formulas

Tags: validation, settings

Could someone please help me with the following: I want to validate the documents added in sharepoint only if they have the Project name and the Contractor name. Can you please let me know what formula can I use? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the Project Name and Contract Name are column fields or content inside document ?

Comment: you can make these columns as required field. In this case document will be uploaded but will not be visible for other users as it will be checked out to you. Is this what you are looking for or something else ?

Comment: I would like to make people give a Project name and Contractor name for all the uploaded documents, ad if once they try uploading, the fields are not filled, have a message like: Project and Contractor name required.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test

- The Project name is not blank

AND

- The Contract name is not blank

The Formula:

```
=AND(  NOT( ISBLANK([Project name]) ) , NOT( ISBLANK([Contractor name]) )  )
```

Comment: Hi Danny, thank you for your email. It doesn't work for me though. I can still check out docs without having the names on the two columns

Comment: ah, I thought you need this when adding documents to SP. Once in SP that check won;t work. You can create a View to list incorrect tagged documents.

Comment: HI Danny, I need that formula for when adding documents in SP, so you were right in doing that assumption. I never worked with SP before, so I thought the formula applies when you want to check out the documents.

Comment: Can you think of any reason or other setting I need to do in order to make that formula work?

Comment: You can only Check Out documents that are allready **in** SharePoint. Also.. if you copy Documents into SP with **Windows Explorer** you can never validate them with these formulas. One option is to create a **View** with documents that do not have proper metadata and check visually. Note: you can set an **Alert** on that View so you get an email notification.